# Replace multiple elements using replace with in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` and `button` that I need to replace with new ones. I use `replaceWith` in jquery to achieve this but it seems that I'm doing it wrongly.

This is my javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', 'div', function(){
     $('textarea, button').replaceWith('<textarea>New</textarea><button>Old</button>');
     });
});
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<textarea>Old</textarea>
<button>Old</button>

<div>Replace</div>
```

Clicking the `Replace` div should replace both the `Old` text area and the button with the new ones but for some reason it leads to displaying 2 text areas and 2 buttons.

Tried using `$('textarea', 'button')` but this does nothing at all.

Comment: Do you mean to replace the text in both textarea and button with 'New' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If per your comments elsewhere you cannot split the two elements apart for text purposes, then alternatively you should ensure that both existing elements share a common parent (e.g. a `<div>`) and then replace the *contents* of that parent:

```
<div id="parent">
  <textarea>Old</textarea>
  <button>Old</button>
</div>

$('#parent').empty().append(newContent);
```

Alternatively if you cannot change the downloaded HTML, then within the event handler if you can assume that there are no other matching elements between the "replace" div and the original content:

```
$(this).prevAll('button').first().remove();
$(this).prevAll('textarea').first().remove();
$(this).before(newContent);
```

Comment: @MichaelSamuel  which did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the two out, to avoid trying to replace both in the same statement.

```
$('textarea').replaceWith('<textarea>New</textarea>');
$('button').replaceWith('<button>Old2</button>');
```

Comment: Thanks but it I can't do it like this as the new elements are contained in a variable so can't break them down like this